# Creating a thread safe atomic counter

Tags: c++, windows

I have a specific requirement in one of the my projects, that is keeping "count" of certain operations and eventually "reading" + "resetting" these counters periodically (eg. 24 hours).

Operation will be:

- Worker threads -> increment counters (randomly)
- Timer thread (eg. 24 hours) -> read count -> do something -> reset counters

The platform I am interested in is Windows, but if this can be cross platform even better. I'm using Visual Studio and target Windows architecture is **x64 only**.

I am uncertain if the result is "ok" and if my implementation is correct. Frankly, never used much std wrappers and my c++ knowledge is quite limited.

Result is:

```
12272 Current: 2
12272 After: 0
12272 Current: 18
12272 After: 0
12272 Current: 20
12272 After: 0
12272 Current: 20
12272 After: 0
12272 Current: 20
12272 After: 0
```

Below is a fully copy/paste reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>

class ThreadSafeCounter final 
{
private:
    std::atomic_uint m_Counter1;
    std::atomic_uint m_Counter2;
    std::atomic_uint m_Counter3;
public:
    ThreadSafeCounter(const ThreadSafeCounter&) = delete;
    ThreadSafeCounter(ThreadSafeCounter&&) = delete;
    ThreadSafeCounter& operator = (const ThreadSafeCounter&) = delete;
    ThreadSafeCounter& operator = (ThreadSafeCounter&&) = delete;

    ThreadSafeCounter() : m_Counter1(0), m_Counter2(0), m_Counter3(0) {}
    ~ThreadSafeCounter() = default;

    std::uint32_t IncCounter1() noexcept 
    {
        m_Counter1.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) + 1;
        return m_Counter1;
    }

    std::uint32_t DecCounter1() noexcept
    {
        m_Counter1.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) - 1;
        return m_Counter1;
    }

    VOID ClearCounter1() noexcept
    {
        m_Counter1.exchange(0);
    }
};

int main()
{
    static ThreadSafeCounter Threads;

    auto Thread1 = []() {
        while (true)
        {
            auto test = Threads.IncCounter1();
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Threads.IncCounter1() -> " << test << std::endl;

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        }
    };

    auto Thread2 = []() {
        while (true)
        {
            auto test = Threads.DecCounter1();
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Threads.DecCounter1() -> " << test << std::endl;

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        }
    };

    auto Thread3 = []() {
        while (true)
        {
            Threads.ClearCounter1();
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Threads.ClearCounter1()" << std::endl;

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        }
    };

    std::thread th1(Thread1);
    std::thread th2(Thread2);
    std::thread th3(Thread3);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    th3.join();
}
```

I should mention that in my real life project there is no usage of std::thread wrapper, and the threads are created using WinApi functions like CreateThread. The above is just to simulate/test the code.

Please point out to me what is wrong with the above code, what could be improved and if I'm on the right direction at all.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question first says the program "works", but then immediately says there are "issues", followed by some output but with no explanation on what the problem with the output is.

Comment: @paddy Sorry, been working too many hours. In essence, the first thing that bothers me: "Threads.DecCounter1() -> 4294967295" - should be 0?

Comment: Why should it be zero?  It was just reset to zero on the line above, and then another thread decrements it.  I don't understand why that's a concern, honestly.  Your threads are independently running low-resolution imprecise timers.  Even though they each sleep for (a minimum of) 2 seconds, there is no guarantee that they'll stay in sync with one another at all.  It's entirely plausible that over the course of a full day, any of those threads has one or more fewer timer events than any other.

Comment: @paddy I understand. This is just a test/playground, in the real life app nothing is certain and this is not the way it will be used exactly. I mentioned this at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Then I don't understand the issue.  If you want to stress-test your counter to ensure it's actually atomic, then spawn hundreds of threads that simultaneously increment or decrement the counter millions of times, and engineer the parameters of the test so that you can know what the final count should be.  Then you just run the program, wait for the threads to complete and check the value is what it should be.  Of course, any kind of "net-zero" test is bogus once you add "reset" into the mix.

Comment: You're assuming that your functions like `IncCounter1()` are atomic, but they are not.  One possible explanation of the behaviour you're seeing is that one thread is calling `IncCounter1()` which is interrupted after calling `m_Counter1.fetch_add()` but before reaching the `return` statement by other threads calling `DecCounter1()` and `ClearCounter1()`.   Change `IncCounter1()` to something like `return m_Counter1.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) + 1`.  Similarly for other operations.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated my post with my exact requirement.

Comment: Why do you use a lock to protect your atomic counters? The atomics are meant to handle concurrent accesses.

Comment: @JánosBenjaminAntal I know, it's just as "precaution" in case something wants to go terribly wrong in my app. Those are "slim" locks so they are not noticeable.

Comment: But then don't use atomics. All of the write functions of `ThreadSafeCounter` is protected with an exclusive locks, the reader one with a shared lock, so I don't see why do you want to use atomics. So I would keep only locks or only the atomics, but not both of them. The locks are easier to use for sure, but they basically defeats the biggest advantage of atomics in this case.

Comment: @JánosBenjaminAntal Sure, I'm not arguing with that. If you have a better example/solution feel free to post it :)

Comment: Apparently you have edited your question after initially asked, as answers point out errors in atomics use, and now as you use SRWLOCK, you don't need atomics at all. Please don't do that as it invalidates existing answers! Note that the code with locks is expected to be slower than atomics original code, but if you don't care then it is fine. Use `std::mutex` as cross-platform SRWLOCK alternative.

Comment: I'm thinking that this looks a bit overly complex. First, I would make the `ThreadSafeCounter` only deal with _one_ counter. You can make an array of them if you need three. Also, wouldn't the normal pre increment/decrement operators do just fine instead of `fetch`ing and adding/subtracting afterwards? [example](https://godbolt.org/z/dPaWxnaKo). With this simplification I can't help to wonder, wouldn't a `std::array<std::atomic<std::uint32_t>, 3>` do instead of making this class?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for your input, I really like your idea. I haven't thought about std::array, even though I use it a lot. I guess my only question at this point would be, why are you not using fetch_add/fetch_suv/load?

Comment: @Mecanik I didn't see the need for fetching and then adding afterwards. The preincrement operator returns a copy of the value after increment.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Interesting, also in your code example I see you are not running the threads simultaneously, and you are only working on the first counter. Is this for any reason or?

Comment: @Mecanik I only worked on one to show a minimal example. It's ok to work on all of them. I delayed the start of deccrement and clear to see the output properly. You can start the at the same time, that's ok, but the output will seem to come out of order more often.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, I really like your approach. If you post an answer I will consider accepting it as official.

Comment: @Mecanik Cool. I'll think about it and maybe come back with a proper answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why are you writing a `ThreadSafeCounter` class at all?

`std::atomic<size_t>` ***is*** a ThreadSafeCounter. That's the whole point of std::atomic. So you should use it instead. No need for another class. Most atomics have operator++/operator-- specializations, so your main loop could easily be rewritten like this:

```
    static std::atomic_int ThreadCounter1(0);

    auto Thread1 = []() {
        while (true)
        {
            auto test = ++ThreadCounter1;  // or ThreadCounter1++, whatever you need
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Threads.IncCounter1() -> " << test << std::endl;

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        }
    };

    auto Thread2 = []() {
        while (true)
        {
            auto test = --ThreadCounter1;
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Threads.DecCounter1() -> " << test << std::endl;

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        }
    };

    auto Thread3 = []() {
        while (true)
        {
/* Note: You could simply "ThreadCounter1 = 0" assign it here.
But exchange not only assigns a new value, it returns the previous value.
*/
            auto ValueAtReset=ThreadCounter1.exchange(0);
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Threads.ClearCounter1() called at value" << ValueAtReset << std::endl;

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        }
    };
```

I forgot to mention a problem with your DecCounter operation. You are using atomic_uint, which cannot handle negative numbers. But there is no guarantee, that your Thread2 will not run (aka decrement the counter) before Thread1. Which means that your counter will wrap.

So you could/should use `std::atomic<int>` instead. That will give you the correct number of (calls_Thread1 - calls_Thread2). The number will get negative if Thead2 has decremented the value more often than Thread1.

Comment: Though I think an important part is `operator++` and `operator--` works based on `fetch_add` and `fetch_sub` with the default memory order, which is `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, therefore I would suggest to use `fetch_xxx` explicitly with proper memory order. Apart from that I think your approach is fine, if the extra class is not necessary (I assumed there are other functionalities).

Comment: You are right of course about the memory order.  However, unless performance is really critical - *and* the inc/dec operations have been proven to be the culprit - I would still recommend operator++/-- for clarity. Also I didn't want to make the matter complicated here. The intricacies of the memory order are difficult to grasp and are worth an extra stackoverflow question :)

Answer (score 2):

This looks suspicious:

```
std::uint32_t IncCounter1() noexcept 
{
    m_Counter1.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) + 1;
    return m_Counter1;
}
```

The `+ 1` is at the end of that line is effectively a no-op since the code does not assign the result of that expression to anything. Further, you create a race condition by referencing `m_Counter1` again on the second line - as there could have easily been a context switch to another thread changing it's value between performing the `fetch_add` and then referencing the value again for the return result.

I think you want this instead:

```
std::uint32_t IncCounter1() noexcept 
{
    return m_Counter1.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) + 1;
}
```

`fetch_add` will return the previously held value before the increment. So returning that `+1` will be the current value of the counter at that moment.

Same issue in DecCounter1.  Change that function's implementation to be this:

```
std::uint32_t DecCounter1() noexcept
{
    return m_Counter1.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) - 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've done this change. Frankly, I would set these functions as VOID but for testing now I need the return value.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated my post with my exact requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be an issue depending on how these counters are used. If a lot of `DecCounter1` and a `ClearCounter1` (or more) is called around the same time, then it might happen that `ClearCounter1` sets the counter to `0`, then a lot of `DefCounter1` is executed (before the lock was preventing them to do so), and the counter ends up being negative. This can be a problem when:

1. The counters are used for any kind of resource management (releasing memory/files/etc based on the value of counters)
2. The counters are used only for some statistics, but the value of the counters are not proportional to the number of threads. E.g.: if 8 event happens during the day that you want to count, but there are more than 8 threads, then in a very unlucky situation (when the events are happening around the same time as resetting the counter) you might end up a wrong starting value for the next period which makes the statistic inaccurate.

If any of the above is true, then the situation is much harder and I haven't though about it yet. For a simple, statistic like counters I think the code can be improved: the atomics and the locks are doing almost the same and by locking you might degrade the performance without gaining anything (all of the above problems are true regarding whether your are using locks, atomics or both). Therefore I would just get rid of the locks and use purely atomics. Here is my proposal for an improved version **in case of none of the above mentioned problems apply**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>


class ThreadSafeCounter final
{
private:
  std::atomic_uint32_t m_Counter1;
  std::atomic_uint32_t m_Counter2;
  std::atomic_uint32_t m_Counter3;
public:
  ThreadSafeCounter(const ThreadSafeCounter&) = delete;
  ThreadSafeCounter(ThreadSafeCounter&&) = delete;
  ThreadSafeCounter& operator = (const ThreadSafeCounter&) = delete;
  ThreadSafeCounter& operator = (ThreadSafeCounter&&) = delete;

  ThreadSafeCounter() : m_Counter1(0), m_Counter2(0), m_Counter3(0) {}
  ~ThreadSafeCounter() = default;

  void IncCounter1() noexcept
  {
    m_Counter1.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
  }

  void DecCounter1() noexcept
  {
    m_Counter1.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
  }

  std::uint32_t GetTotalCounter1()
  {
    return m_Counter1.load();
  }

  std::uint32_t GetAndClearCounter1()
  {
    return m_Counter1.exchange(0);
  }
};

int main()
{
  static ThreadSafeCounter Threads;

  auto WorkerThread1 = []() {
    while (true)
    {
      Threads.IncCounter1();
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
  };

  auto WorkerThread2 = []() {
    while (true)
    {
      Threads.DecCounter1();
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
    }
  };

  auto FinalThread = []() {
    while (true)
    {
      auto Current = Threads.GetTotalCounter1();
      std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Current: " << Current << std::endl;

      const auto Before = Threads.GetAndClearCounter1();
      std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Before: " << Before << std::endl;

      auto After = Threads.GetTotalCounter1();
      std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " After: " << After << std::endl;

      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
  };

  std::thread th1(WorkerThread1);
  std::thread th2(WorkerThread2);
  std::thread th3(FinalThread);

  th1.join();
  th2.join();
  th3.join();
}
```

The changes I made:

1. I removed the lock, because it doesn't give anything extra in my opinion.
2. I replaced `m_Counter1.fetch_sub(0)` by `m_Counter1.load()` because it does the same thing, but the load operation is obvious.
3. I replaced the `atomic_uint` type by `atomic_uint32_t` just to match the type of the return value of `GetTotalCounter1`.
4. Added a function `GetAndClearCounter1` to guarantee that there is no other operation is happening between reading and clearing the value.
5. Removed the unused `+ 1` and `- 1` in `IncCounter1` and `DecCounter1`.
6. Changed the `VOID` return types to `void`, because in my opinion `void` is more idiomatic.

As a final verdict, I think reading over the [documentation of `std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) can be really helpful. It isn't the shortest docs, but definitely detailed enough to get familiar with operations, memory order etc.

Comment: If you worry about going negative (or unsigned wrap-around), shouldn't you switch to compare_exchange? At least for the decrement.

Comment: You can use compare exchange in a way to get the value, check if it is larger than `0`, then use `compare_exchange` to check if the value has changed and decrement if not. But what should happen, if the value is changed? If you retry it, then you can easily get into an infinite loop. I would without further knowledge about the exact use-case (when a decrement can happen, etc) I wouldn't try to solve this, because it will be a big mess.